# ASP.net UpdatePanel Dropdown Render Issue

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

i am at starter level in asp.net i was developing a small application just to add students to database, main reason was to use update panel but when I use AsyncPostBack trigger the dropdown box does not render properly but with normal PostBack it does I am assuming i am missing out something the code has nothing special i just used  and  inside  and  here is an image that can describe it better

here is a link screenshot of what's happening : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/dfpw.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using any Jquery plugin to make normal dropdownlist as fancy as looking in the screenshot attached.. if that is the case call the same plugin in the pageLoad() function too as after partial postback happens, the dropdown looses it's appearance and looking like normal dropdownlist.

Comment: By calling in page load, do you mean adding via literal control?